# Convert byte array code from c to swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, byte

I have this line in a header file at an objective c project.

```
static const char my_bytes[] = { -30, 10, 90}
```

I want to write it in swift, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let my_bytes : [CChar] = [-30, 10, 90]
```

`CChar` is simply an alias for `Int8`. You can read more about it in [Interacting with C API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).